# How can I make JavaScript run in WebBrowser control?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, winforms, webbrowser-control

In my winforms aplication I have a WebBrowser control named webBrowser1.

In code all I added is navigating to a page:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    webBrowser1.Navigate("http://localhost:6489/Default.aspx");
}
```

The code for the page to which I navigate is:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="TableRowShow.Default" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      window.onload = function()
      {
        document.getElementById('addDestination').setAttribute('onclick', 'addDest();');
      }

      function attach()
      {
        document.getElementById('addDestination').setAttribute('onclick', 'addDest();');
      }

      var i = 1; // position of next tr to be shown

      function addDest()
      {
        var trs = document.getElementById('travelTable').getElementsByTagName('tr');

        if (trs[i] != null)
          trs[i++].style.display = "";
      }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
      <table id="travelTable">
        <tr>
          <td>
            <asp:TextBox runat="server" />
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr style="display: none">
          <td>
            <asp:TextBox runat="server" />
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr style="display: none">
          <td>
            <asp:TextBox runat="server" />
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
      <asp:HyperLink runat="server" ID="addDestination"
        ClientIDMode="Static"  NavigateUrl="javascript:;" >
        Add Destination
      </asp:HyperLink>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Seen in a browser like IE or Chrome the page looks like this:

[image]

Clicking on Add Destination anchor creates a new input:

[image]

The problem that I'm having with WebBrowser control is that it loads the page but the JavaScript doesn't work.

If I click on Add Destination nothing happens, even though the same page works well in Chrome or IE.

Placing a breakpoint and using:

```
webBrowser1.Document.InvokeScript("addDestination");
```

inside the Immediate window and then continuing to run the program activates the JavaScript in that function adding a new input.

Thanks for replies!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try attaching the click handlers like this instead of using `setAttribute` in the `onload` and `attach` functions:

```
document.getElementById('addDestination').onclick = addDest;
```

Comment: That fixed the problem. Any ideea why it doesn't work using setAttribute since in other browsers it works? I am using IE8 in windows and it works. Doesn't WebBrowser use IE8 also (latest IE installed)?

Answer (score 0):

You could try setting the [`ScriptErrorsSuppressed`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.scripterrorssuppressed.aspx) property to `false` to see whether any JavaScript errors occur.

Comment: I tried setting it to false (added that before the navigate line) but no errors appeared. Where are the errors supposed to be seen?

Comment: From what I know, a message box should appear.